# Jest: Test environment node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to run some tests on my ECMAScript modules using `jest`. I read here that `jest` provides experimental support for ECMAScript modules,

https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

However, when I try to execute this, I keep running into the following error,

```
● Validation Error:

  Test environment node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js cannot be found. Make sure the testEnvironment configuration option points to an existing node module.
```

Both my test module and the module that I am trying to test are ECMAScript modules with the `.mjs` extension.

This is what my `jest.config.js` file looks like,

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js',
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/**/*.test.mjs'
  ],
  transform: {},
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$'
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'mjs',
    'json',
    'node'
  ],
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true
    }
  }
};
```

My package.json,
{

```
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "mindsdb-js-sdk": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

This is the structure of my project,

```
my-project/
├── config/
│   └── config.js
├── node_modules/
├── src/
│   └── myModule.mjs
├── jest.config.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── tests/
    ├── myModule.test.mjs
```

What am I doing wrong? If this is not the right way to go about it, how can I run my tests?

Comment: Where exactly in the docs you link to did you get the idea that `testEnvironment: 'node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js'` would be valid configuration? See https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string for the kinds of values you'd pass there.